# SPD 2013 Compound Condition causing Workflow Error

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a List workflow created using SPD 2013. My first stage contains an "If any value equals any value" condition. It passes error check with no errors.

As soon as I click below the existing If condition and add a second If condition, resulting in a compound If condition like so:

[image]

I get a workflow error like this:[image]

When I click on Visual Designer View, I can see that the error is related to my compound condition. "An error was detected when validating the properties of this shape." When I click on the shape and Properties, nothing happens.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what changed...but the error went away. All I can think is that I had to close and open SPD.